# mysqldump locks all tables even when specifically grabbing a few?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I'm using a mysqldump command pulling data from 3 tables of 7. Are the other 4 locked as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use `--single-transaction` option, and it won't lock any, provided you are using a transaction-aware storage engine (pretty much anything except MyISAM and MEMORY engines)

Comment: I'm aware of --single-transaction to not lock any, I'm just wondering if the default set up is to lock _every single table_ in the database until the mysqldump is complete, regardless of the fact that I'm only pulling a finite number of them.